# Got the Error: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I applied this code:

```
# Counting genre_id
def genre_id_count(x):
    if x == 'no_genre_id':
        return 0
    else:
        return x.count('|') + 1

# filling NA in place of null values
train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
test['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
train['genre_ids_count'] = train['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count).astype(np.int8)
test['genre_ids_count'] = test['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count).astype(np.int8)
```

But, got the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-410362445e25> in <module>
     11 train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
     12 test['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
---> 13 train['genre_ids_count'] = train['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count).astype(np.int8)
     14 test['genre_ids_count'] = test['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count).astype(np.int8)

ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your dataframe.

Comment: Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code does not work is the following: when you apply `train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id')` then this method returns a new pandas series. You apply `.fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)` to this new series. As you set `inplace=True`, this new series is modified - and it is removed from memory right after the execution of the command, because it was not stored in a variable.

Since the original series `train['genre_ids']` is not modified, it still contains NA values. Integer columns cannot contain nan-values in pandas (this is only possible for float columns) so that pandas does not know how to convert these values into integers and your code fails.

In order to prevent this, you have to options: you can either write

```
train['genre_ids'] = train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id')
```

or you can use

```
train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
train['genre_ids'].fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
```

In the first version, both methods `cat.add_categories` and `fillna` do not modify the original series but create new ones and return them. The method `fillna` is applied to the output of `cat.add_categories` - and the output of `fillna` is then used to override the original series `train['genre_ids']`.

In the second version, both methods modify the original series and return nothing. However, since `cat.add_categories` modifies the original series and does not return anything, we cannot chain the methods and you have to call both of them directly on `train['genre_ids']`.

Comment: train['genre_ids'].head()
0     359
1    1259
2    1259
3    1019
4    1011
Name: genre_ids, dtype: category
Categories (1045, object): ['1000', '1000|2154|751', '1007', '1011', ..., '986', '986|1955', '993', '993|751']

Comment: print('Adding new features')
​
# Counting genre_id
def genre_id_count(x):
    if x == 'no_genre_id':
        return 0
    else:
        return x.count('|') + 1
    
# filling NA in place of null values
train['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
test['genre_ids'].cat.add_categories('no_genre_id').fillna('no_genre_id', inplace=True)
train['genre_ids_count'] = train['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count)
​
train['genre_ids_count'].isna().sum()
Adding new features
118455

Comment: train['genre_ids'] is category type and yes it is containing the na values, what could be the solution?

Comment: train[train['genre_ids_count'].isna()]['genre_ids_count']
29        NaN
151       NaN
163       NaN
395       NaN
531       NaN
           ..
7377296   NaN
7377320   NaN
7377330   NaN
7377331   NaN
7377370   NaN
Name: genre_ids_count, Length: 118455, dtype: float64

Comment: Now, I have applied .fillna(0) not throwing error : train['genre_ids_count'] = train['genre_ids'].apply(genre_id_count).fillna(0).astype(np.int8)                                                  Is it fine?

Comment: I modified my original answer - I hope this explains the problem well now.